# 'Extrapolate' a probability density to a different support

Tags: distributions, spatial

here is my scenario:

I have N triangles and N probability distributions (of independent variables), and the support of the ith probability distribution is just the ith triangle.

The triangles may differ in size and shape, but the idea is that the different probability distributions are kind of "similar" (e.g. in the sense that they all have a maximum somewhere in the center of their appropriate triangle and decrease towards the edges...)

Now I have a completely new triangle and I want to assign to it a probability distribution that best fits in with the distributions I already have.

So, intuitively, the more a triangle i among the N given ones is similar to my new triangle, the more I would want the new distribution to be close to the ith given one.

---

My first approach would be to define a metric on the set of triangles (probably Hausdorff distance), and to define the new probability distribution in terms of a weighted sum of the given distributions, where the weights depend on the 'distance' of the new triangle to the approriate given one. What remains to be done is to "squash and stretch" the new distribution function so as to adjust its support to the new triangle.

I am not sure if this is the most generic way to handle the problem or if there is a more beautiful theory that I am not aware of.

Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: It may be hard for people to say much about this until you provide clear, operational definitions of "fits in," "similar," and "close"--both for distributions and triangles.